# Does Tumblr not allow animated gifs?

Tags: tumblr

I'm new to Tumblr...

I've tried uploading an animated gif both via the URL and then uploading the actual gif, but it seems to only show the first "frame" from the animated gif. Does anyone know a way around this or does Tumblr just not allow animated gifs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumblr does allow animated gifs to be uploaded, but does place some restrictions on them.

From [Tumblr's Posting Guidelines](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/posting)

> Since resizing animated GIFs is computationally intensive, large files (greater than 512K or wider than 500 pixels) may lose their animation if the upload server runs out of memory. Please avoid uploading unreasonably large animated GIFs.